# Не получается написать запрос на php к методу telegram api

Tags: php, telegram-bot

не получается написать запрос на пхп к методу telegram api getchatinviteimporters. Делаю все по инструкции, но выдает ошибку {"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}. Вот мой код

````
    <?php

$botToken = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN';
$chatId = 'CHAT_ID';
$inviteLink = 'INVITE_LINK';

$apiUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$botToken/getChatInviteImporters";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'chat_id' => $chatId,
    'invite_link' => $inviteLink,
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error sending request: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $response;
}

curl_close($ch);

?>```
````

Comment: а где у ботов есть такой метод? https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getChatInviteImporters

Comment: Эти методы НЕ у ботов

Comment: И даже для текущего метода, не для бота, я что-то не вижу параметров в виде chat_id и invite_link. Это должно быть скорее метод SendMessage или Invite, но явно не getChatInvitations.......Это так, отсупление от темы. Основной посыл всё же, что это не ботовсккий метод